# Call submit button method using JQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following method which is called by asp button click.

```
protected void btn_saveDemographicsAddr_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I want to call the above method using jquery ajax call with out page loading. I saw many
blogs regarding this but i din't get the correct solutions.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Which solutions did you see, and what wasn't correct about them?

Comment: sending button id to jQuery click event.. but that makes page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **UpdatePanel** solve your problem.
Just put your ImageButton control in UpdatePanel and Trigger onclick event, It automatically get your contain without page load.

This link help you more..

http://forums.asp.net/t/1817866.aspx/2/10

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Aspx

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagermAIN" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

c#

```
[WebMethod]
public void btn_saveDemographicsAddr_Click()
{
}
```

Javascript

```
PageMethods.btn_saveDemographicsAddr_Click();
```

For more info about scriptmanager go to [scriptmanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager_properties.aspx)

Comment: what about (object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj Just add an html button and on click call javascript. Or on client click of your button execute javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
     `About.aspx page
    using System.Web.Services;

    [WebMethod]
    public static string doSomething(int id)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "About.aspx/doSomething",
            data: "{'id':'1'}",
            dataType: "Json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var returnedstring = data.d;
                ....
            }
        });
    });
```